# Is my understanding of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}(1, 0) + \mathbb{Z}(1, 3)$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

I am asked to sketch at least 15 points of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}(1, 0) + \mathbb{Z}(1, 3)$.

From my understanding of lattices, that means sketching at least 15 points that are linear combinations of the vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 3)$, correct? In other words, any point P in that lattice can be written in the following notation:

$P = A(1, 0) + B(1, 3)$, with $A$ and $B$ being any integers, including $0$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}(1, 0) + \mathbb{Z}(1, 3) = \mathbb{Z}(1, 0) + \mathbb{Z}(0, 3)$.

Comment: Yes, correct. Mark these points in a coordinate system.